# Is it possible to use the sleep() function in iOS to create animation?

Tags: ios, ipad, sleep

I tried using sleep(1) to create animation, but it did something odd.

```
        [self.guySprite stopAnimating];
        self.guySprite.hidden = YES;
        sleep(1);
        self.objectSprite.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jumpToSleep.png"];
```

In this code, "guySprite" is a UIView, and so is "objectSprite".

For some reason, the "guySprite seems to act as if "stop animating" wasn't called, and as if it wasn't hidden.

Comment: Nothing happens during `sleep()`, the task is "asleep". Don't ever call sleep().

Comment: But if nothing happens, why does it start animating again?  shouldn't it just continue not animating?